# Has any research used Bayesian networks to estimate risk factor betas?

Tags: statistics, r, machine-learning, risk-models, factor-models

Is there any published research on estimating the beta of a security with respect to one or more risk factors via Bayesian networks?

I'd like to see if this is a promising angle of research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One relevant paper is:

> Shenoy, C. and Shenoy, P.P., Bayesian network models of portfolio risk and return, 1999. [**PDF**](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.142.5138&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: A related text is also Rebonato's "Coherent Stress Testing: A Bayesian Approach"